# Android Show Dialog From a Service on error

Tags: android, android-service, google-play-services, android-location

I have a `Service` that implements `GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener`.

So, when I create the `Service` I check to see if `Google Play Services` is available, or at the correct version:

```
private boolean servicesConnected() {

  // Check that Google Play services is available
  int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

  // If Google Play services is available
  if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == resultCode) {
      return true;
  } else {
    // Get the error code
      GooglePlayServicesUtil
          .getErrorDialog(resultCode, this, 0).show();// This won't work in a service
  }

}//end
```

So, if I return an error code, how can I respond to it (showing the user a `Dialog` with options) since I am inside of a `Service`? What is the best practices in this circumstance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best practice is that Services are meant to be only for Long task "NON UI Related" functionality, if you need to show even a message chances that you don't need a Service are high, they are supposed to be 100% background long task functionality, according to Google's Documentation. Actually having to show an error message or something related to the UI would be a good sign to look for a different approach to whatever you are doing, anyway if it's so important to show the message i assume your activity should be visible, you can always bind a service to your activity and executed a method on it that shows the dialog...

Hope this Help...

Regards!

Comment: Alright. So you are saying I should do the `Google Play Services` check before I ever even start my service. Correct?

Comment: @NicHubbard: Correct.

Comment: If that will prevent you from coupling your Service to some sort of "UI" feedback, definitely...

Comment: Perfect. Thanks guys. It is kind of obvious now. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can always launch an activity in a service.

Comment: Isn't this bad application design though? Are you meaning, create an `Activity` to pass into the `getErrorDialog()` function?